# Clarity clr-datagrid use custom filter markup, but retain built-in filtering/sorting functionality

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

How can I provide my own custom markup for the `clr-dg-column` components that tie into the parent `clr-datagrid` component's sorting/filtering functionalities?

I want to provide a simple text input (or any custom markup) that's always visible (instead of being hidden in the filter popup), but I want to retain all of the functionality that the Clarity framework provides out of the box for sorting/filtering the datagrid's data. I expect the sorting/filtering behavior that the `clr-datagrid` component provides out of the box to work with my custom markup. By this I mean internally a `clr-dg-column` component that includes a `clrDgField` binding will update the parent `clr-datagrid` component's internal state. If the parent `clr-datagrid` component has a `clrDgRefresh` binding on it (for server-driven data), then the internal state will be passed to the bound function. I want all of that to work.

Is there a way to wire custom HTML up to the parent `clr-datagrid` component's sorting/filter functionality? Here's an example of what I'm going for:

```
<clr-dg-column>
  <span>{{myColumnName}}</span> <!-- I want to wire this up so it can still be used to sort when clicked on -->
  <div class="filter-wrapper">
    <input type="text" /> <!-- I want to wire this up so it still filters the column -->
  </div>
</clr-dg-column>
```

and I want it to behave functionally equivalent to something like this:

```
<clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'my_column'">
  <span>{{myColumnName}}</span>
</clr-dg-column>
```

Comment: You don't really want the default functionality if you want it always to show. If you you want to create a filter with custom HTML, I could answer that but won't since your question is unclear and too broad. This is why you should always make sure questions on SO are about one single problem, never two separate issues. I have also kind dealt with your other problem, I needed a text box to search all fields to display outside of the grid, but I just handled it separately, outside of the grid.

Comment: You should clarity your question. The first statement is "How would one go about using custom HTML for the Clarity datagrid sorting and filters?"

Comment: @JuanMendes Please let me know how I can clarify my question. I'm happy to provide more info in order to make it more specific. When I say I want it to 'behave functionally equivalent' I'm saying that the built-in filters tie in with the datagrid's internal state and I want my custom filter markup to do the same. In addition to that clicking on a column header driven by a clr-dg-column that has a [clrDgField] binding on it will sort the column. I want to be able to tie into both the sort and filter functionalities all while providing my own markup that will display inline underneath the header

Comment: @JuanMendes Updated - hopefully my question is more clear now.